# "No media found" bootloader totally messed up

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi, boot-repair

I tried to make a dual boot from ubuntu and windows 10. The thing is, I once tried to do de same thing but with ubuntu and windows 8.1, but things went wrong because of UEFI and I wasn't even able to boot windows. I tried boot repair with a bootable usb drive and the solution that a I got was that I could boot windows but to boot ubuntu I needed to go to advanced restart in windows and then it would start ubuntu as a device (no ideia how things got so messed up).

So today I tried to solve that problem by instaling ubuntu with the option of instaling alongside windows boot manager. It did not solve the problem, and this time I have "no media found" error when I start windows. Then the computor restarts and windows boots normaly but I can't boot ubuntu.

This is the report I got from boot-repair: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12021549/

Can anyone help me?

Comment: It looks like you have ubuntu entry first in UEFI and it does not like that, so then goes to second entry to boot. Some systems particularly HP & Sony and maybe now Toshiba have modified UEFI to include description in UEFI boot. And only valid description is "Windows". Several work arounds but most copy shim into /EFI/Boot & rename to bootx64.efi. That is a hard drive boot entry or fallback entry. You may need to add an UEFI hard drive entry. Not sure if current entry is BIOS or UEFI. http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789

Answer (score 0):

Given that Boot Repair hasn't helped, I recommend you try the USB flash drive or CD-R version of my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) (You'll need to disable Secure Boot, at least temporarily, to get it to boot.) If rEFInd can boot both Windows and Ubuntu, try installing it using the PPA or Debian package. If that works, then great; but if the system boots straight to Windows after you restart, you may need to perform an ugly hack that involves renaming boot loader files. Instructions for rEFInd on how to do this are [in the rEFInd documentation.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#naming)